# Counting binary digits in a list of excel cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to make a formula that transforms a list decimal numbers to binary, then counts the number of appearances of ones at a certain position. I was trying to build an array formula that went something like this:

```
{=SUM(MID(DEC2BIN(A1:A10;10);9;1)}
```

This will return #VALUE. Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: examples added

```
Input       (Binary Equivalent)

  2             0000000010     
  3             0000000101 
  7             0000000111 
  7             0000000111 
  5             0000000101 
  9             0000001001

 Outputs          Result
(digit to sum
from the right)

  1                 5
  2                 3
  3                 3
  4                 1
```

Comment: Post some example inputs with desired output. Are you trying to see how many of the decimal numbers have the 2nd binary digit set for example?

Comment: Your error is because `DEC2BIN` can't accept a range as its input

Comment: @Dan It can; it just requires a little extra coercion: https://excelxor.com/2014/11/04/coercing-array-returns-from-cse-resistant-formulas/ See the comments at the foot of this post for Lori's simple improvement, i.e. =SUM(0+MID(DEC2BIN(-A1:A10,10),9,1))

Comment: Edit: that should be  =SUM(0+MID(DEC2BIN(--A1:A10,10),9,1)), as per the solution posted below.

Comment: @XORLX I still don't understand why the `-` makes it no longer a syntax error?

Comment: @Dan At the foot of the post I mentioned Lori offers an attempt at an explanation as to why such coercions are necessary for certain functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to count have many of the second digits are set in a range of numbers you can do this:

```
={SUM((MOD(A1:A10,4)>=2)+0)}
```

To understand this, let's look at some example data

[image]

Here I have some decimal numbers with their binary equivalents. In column C I have just extracted the 2nd digit (i.e. your `MID(A1,9,1)`). Then in column D I just take the modulo by `4`. You can see that when the remainder is greater than `2`, the second digit is set.

`MOD(A1,4)` basically divides the number by `4` and gives us the remainder (the numerator of the remainder if it was represented as a fraction over `4`). With binary numbers, division by a power of two is just a right shift. Division by `4` is a right shift by `2` and the numbers that 'fall off' are the remainder. In this case it's the first two digits. They can be

```
00 | 0
01 | 1
10 | 2
11 | 3
```

so we see that the second digit is set only when the remainder is greater than 2.

Note the `+0` in the original formula is to cast the boolean result of `=` to an integer so we can use `SUM` i.e. `SUM({TRUE,FALSE})` doesn't work but `SUM({TRUE,FALSE}+0)` computes to `SUM({1,0})` which does work.

To make this generic, let's assume you want to do it for the `$E$1`th digit:

```
=SUM((MOD(A1:A12,2^$E$1)>=2^($E$1-1))+0)
```

Comment: Seems to work perfectly, thanks! One question though, why is the "+0" necessary for it to work?

Comment: Neat - also not restricted by dec2bin only working for -512 up to +511.

Answer (score 2):

This was another way e.g. for the second digit from the right

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISODD(A1:A10/2))
```

Divide by 2^(n-1) where n is digit numbered from the right: the ISODD function ignores any fraction that results from the division.

Comment: Nice solution. Why not just `SUM` though?

Comment: Thanks! - you can either use SUM and array-enter the formula, or SUMPRODUCT and enter it normally. TBH I still haven't worked out when SUMPRODUCT works in this way and when it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

`=SUM(0+MID(DEC2BIN(--A1:A10,10),9,1))`

array-entered.

Regards

Comment: Why does the `-` make it work? Do you have a link explaining this odd behaviour? Also, I think you need two negatives otherwise you're getting the 2s complement so `=SUM(0+MID(DEC2BIN(--A1:A10,10),9,1))`

Comment: Ah, yes. Good point re the additional negative. Will correct my post.

Answer (score 1):

With bit operations it's not necessary to treat the number as a string.

```
{=SUM(BITAND(A1:A10;2^(C1-1))/2^(C1-1))}
```

Assuming the position you are looking for is stored in `C1`.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no requirement to put your binary bits in individual cells, you can directly count the one's in a decimal number very simply, by converting it to a binary string, removing the zeros, and measuring the remaining length:

116 = 1110100 , four ones

```
LEN(SUBSTITUTE(DEC2BIN(116,7),"0",""))
```